# Junit for method in controller layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

My rest endpoint looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/mango/{id}")
public Mono<Mango> getMango(@PathVariable("id") final String id){

validateId(id);
return serviceLayer.someMonoData();
}
```

My Junit looks like:

```
@Test
public void method(){

when(serviceLayer.someMonoData()).thenReturn(someResponse);

webTestClient.get()
   .uri(ENDPOINT_URL)
   .headers(headers)
   .exchange()
   .expectStatus()
   .isBadRequest();
}
```

The `validateId(id);` method is supposed to throw custom bad request exception for an invalid id. This method is not reactive.

But the Junit seems to bypass the `validate()` method and proceeds with the service call stub..

What am i missing?

Comment: What is your ENDPOINT_URL value. Also share webTestClient configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reactive you need to construct the flow using reactive operators that will be executed when web flux subscribes to this flow. In you case `validateId` is not part of the flow.

Not sure what is the contract of the `validateId()` but, assuming it's not reactive, you can use

```
return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> validateId(id))
    .then(serviceLayer.someMonoData());
```

Comment: How can i make validateId() method part of the flow ?

Comment: Check code in the answer